# What are some words only used in Hessen?

Tags: standard-german, dialect

I know, that there is a dialect called „Hessisch“, and as someone speaking German in that region, I really did not realize, that something like an accent or different wordings exist here (yeah maybe I‘m lost), specially in someone’s own word usage. It always sounded the same as the language spoken in German television.
So my question: What exactly is different in „Hessisch“ German and are there also specific words, only used in Hessen?

I was confused, whether to ask this question in Englisch or German, because I‘m new here. It‘s like taking the stairs instead of the elevator to get to your apartment above. But for all, it is maybe required.

Comment: Different varieties English use different vocabulary as well, for example the British say 'holiday' where Americans say 'vacation'. In German the situation is similar but more extreme.

Comment: Most German dialects have their own words for some things, it's not only Hessisch. See for example the words in different regions for "attic": http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/dachboden/?child=runde

Comment: Beware that all the answers given so far refer to southern/mid Hessen dialect. In the North of Hessen (Kassel and surrounding area), a rather completely different dialect is used, which is more related to dialects in the south of Lower Saxony and western regions of Thuringia or saxony-Anhalt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It started as a comment, but it grew into an answer instead.

Typical for the Hessian dialect ([not accent](https://www.lexico.com/explore/what-is-the-difference-between-dialect-and-accent)) is the shift from /ʃ/ and /ç/ to /ʒ/ as illustrated in Martin Schneider's [Aschenbecher](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GmbLaEsTZDY&t=4m25s) example.

Within the Hessian dialect, it's also quite common to skip the *n* in an *-en* ending and put more emphasis on the (now) final e. Again, this can be heard in the Aschenbecher example above and also be observerd in the examples below

Numerous examples are listed in [this German online dictionary](https://www.deine-woerter.de/lexikon/hessen/#), where some heuristic rules can already be derived.

*auf* tends to become *uff*

> uffgeblase (aufgeblasen)

*p* tends to become *b*

> Babba (Papa), uffbasse (aufpassen)

*-ig* tends to become *-isch*

> hibbelisch (hibbelig), ferdisch (fertig)

*ck* tends to become *gg*

> aijereggisch (eiereckig), hogge (hocken), Schnuggelsche  (Schnuckelchen)

In summary, a lot of hard sounds become softer.

> What are specific words, only used in Hessen

Iconic Hessian words are

> Aijereggisch, Riwwekuche (Streuselkuchen), babbeln, Bembel, Gude (Begrüßung), (Hut-)simbel,  ...

Meeting older people from Hesse or people who live/grew up in smaller villages are still speaking the dialect, especially towards the south around the Taunus area.

This is mainly based on my observations as a North-German living in Hessen and noticing the differences with regard to my own dialect.

Comment: From someone, who lived more a city life, most of this is really unfamiliar to me (in my own environment). Other people could have a deeper experience on this. I only know „babbeln“ or „Gude“. And that -ig becomes -isch. To that I think I can relate, I thought -isch would be the Standard German pronounciation, such as lebendisch, so people are also using lebendig as how it is really written.

Comment: Typo: Apfelwein instead of Apfelbein.

Comment: @FromAnatolia, standard pronunciation of -ig is -ich, not -isch.

Comment: @HaraldLichtenstein Dann wär's "Äbbelbaa" ...

Comment: Statt "Riwwekuche" wird oft "Riwwelkuche" gesagt. Das Wort ist auch in der Pfalz sehr verbreitet. Andere Schreibweise: "Ribbelkuche", vgl. https://www.kochbar.de/rezept/288854/Hessischer-Krimmel-oder-Ribbelkuche.html

Comment: I wouldn’t include *Äbbelwoi* as a word *characteristic* of Hessia. Yes, it describes a product that is associated with and usually found in Hessia but the word, in its standard form *Apfelwein* is the only reasonable German word to describe the product. It’s merely a dialectal pronunciation. Likewise, I wouldn’t say *Weißwurscht* be a word characteristic of Bavarian but *Schmarrn* certainly would be.

Comment: First time I have read or heard "aijereggisch". Are you sure that it isn't a distinct Hessian vocable and should be in the "iconic words" section?

Comment: This probably only applies to older people, but due to the presence of french soldiers after the war, there are some french words that made it into the vocabulary. I remember having heard *chaiselongue* for *Sofa/Couch*, and I think *trottoir* as well.

Comment: While they often switch a d for a t and a sch for a g, there's also the opposite way. Price tag on a farmer's market: "Preise trastig gesenkt !". Yeah, i too had to think a moment ... :-)

Comment: @kutschkem: i.e. *Schesslong* and *Trottwa*...

Comment: You mainly describe Hessian as it is spoken in Frankfurt. I live 50 km northeast of Frankfurt in the region Wetterau. Words and pronunciation differ a lot here from what you call Hessian. There is not the one Hessian, it's a group of dialects. See the answer of @HenningKockerbeck.

Comment: @TobiasKnauss "especially towards the south around the Taunus area"

Comment: It's not special to the south. Northern Hesse (Kassel and around) also has strong dialects and they are even more different from those in the Rhine-Main region. Also, I wouldn't see my place as part of the Taunus area...

Comment: That's exactly my point.

Answer (score 7):

To go a bit into the weeds, there's not *the* Hessian dialect. There's [a group of dialects](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessische_Dialekte) that are spoken in Hesse (but also in parts of Franconia, Rheinland-Pfalz and Westfalia) that are sometimes summarized as "Hessian dialect". What you hear in the media sometimes, with people like Martin Schneider or Bodo Bach, is mostly a [Regiolekt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regiolekt) from the Frankfurt-Rhine-Main area. This [Neuhessisch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuhessischer_Regiolekt) is much closer to Standard German than to the "classic" Hessian dialects. You might say, it's basically Standard German colored with some bits of southern Hessian dialects.

Regarding lists of "Hessian" words, maybe you can get your hands on the [dialect versions of Asterix](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Mundart-Ausgaben_von_Asterix). As of now, there are ten books translated to Neuhessisch, and most (all?) of them include a short "vocabulary list". And the comics are fun to read, too ;)

Answer (score 6):

What are some words only used in Hessen?

This must not be confused with a question concerning the Hessian pronunciation of commonly known words (for example "Äbbelwoi" for "Apfelwein").

I do not believe that there are many words used *exclusively* in Hesse. Perhaps

> [Bembel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bembel)

is one of them, but this is certainly *known* outside Hesse (["Zum Blauen Bock"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zum_Blauen_Bock) was a popular TV-show).

A nice word is

> [Kolter](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kolter)

which denotes a woollen blanket. I have never heard it outside Hesse, but perhaps some friendly commenters will correct me.

Also

> [Babbelwasser](https://www.mundmische.de/bedeutung/28785-Babbelwasser_gesoffen)

could be genuine Hessian ("Hast du Babbelwasser gesoffe?").

A nice word used in Frankfurt is

> [Wasserhäuschen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinkhalle_(Verkaufsstelle))

which is a synonym for *Trinkhalle* or *Kiosk*.

Comment: where I grew up it was more "kolder" and having lived in an english speaking country and seeing some similarities between hessisch and english I wonder if it even comes from "colder"

Answer (score 1):

This page has a number of words that are not in high German (page is in German) https://www.deine-woerter.de/lexikon/hessen/

Here are some that I know from growing up:

"aijereggisch" - egg-shaped, literally: egg-corner-ish

"babbele" - to talk, chat

"beleidischd Lebberworscht" - someone being/ playing being sad, literally: offended liver pate

"Dabbes" - someone ditzy or a fool

"Deetz" - your head

"Gell" - appendix to sentences asking for affirmation, like the Kiwi "ey"

"Kaff" - village

"Kamelle" - old story

"Kneipsche" - kitchen knife

"plaerre" - to cry or be upset, ie the sound a baby makes at times

"Simbel" - simple person/ idiot (again you wonder if this was imported from english)

"Tranfunzel" unmotivated person

A LOT of the other words on that page are simply differently pronounced words from high German, or local colloquialisms made of high german word and pronounced differently. I would not strictly call them words that only exist in hessisch

Comment: This page is already linked in my answer.

Comment: "babbeln", "beleidigte Leberwurst", "gelt" (in Hessian *gell*), "Kaff", "Kamelle", "plärren", "Simpel" and "Tranfunzel" are well-known throughout Germany. Also "Deetz" is known https://www.dwds.de/wb/Dez.

Comment: @infinitezero apologies, I hadn't noticed. The rest is shared from my own upbringing.