# Kennt jemand den Begriff "Goltar"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, austrian

Mein Opa stammt aus dem Lesachtal und dem Mölltal (wechselweise aufgewachsen).

Lt. Ihm bezeichnet ein "Goltar" eine schwere Decke.

Kennt jemand diesen Begriff (noch) und weiß, woher dieses Wort kommt?

Comment: Beide Täler liegen in Oberkärnten, nicht weit von Ost-TIrol entfernt. Dort werden südbairische Dialekte gesprochen. Ich bin aber mit mittelbairischen Dialekten aufgewachsen (habe oststeirische Wurzeln) und da gibt es zum Teil erhebliche Unterschiede im Vokabular. Für schwere Decken kenne ich nur den Begriff [*Tuchent*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Tuchent) der aber mit *Goltar* leider so gar nichts zu tun hat. Auch wenn ich versuche, aus dem Dialektwort ein hochdeutsches Wort zu machen (*"Galter"*), enden meine Recherchen im Sand. Auch die Suche nach einem slowenischen Ursprung brachte nix.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast - oft gehen unsere Dialekte hier ins Slowenische.

Comment: Ja, daher habe ich ja danach gesucht, aber es scheint kein ähnliches slowenisches Wort zu geben.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das Wort kenne ich nicht, aber es ist mit Sicherheit eine Variante des Wortes "Kolter", das in Hessen verwendet wird. Zur Herkunft vgl. [hier](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kolter) und [hier](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemma=kolter).

Man beachte auch DevSolars Antwort zu [Does pronunciation of German words vary a lot across different places in Germany?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/4735/34192)

Vgl. auch [Südhessisches Wörterbuch](https://www.lagis-hessen.de/de/subjects/index/sn/shwb), Suchbegriff "Kolter".

Comment: Das scheint Sinn zu ergeben. Wir Österreicher sind dialektmäßig sehr Frankophil. Ich lese mir das etwas Genauer durch

Comment: Ja, das scheint die richtige Quelle zu sein. Siehe auch https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kolter und https://www.dwds.de/wb/Kolter sowie https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kolter_Decke Interessanterweise wird im Duden das Wort *Kotzen* als Synonym angeführt. Das Wort *"Kotzen"* verbinde ich allerdings eher mit einer Schmutzdecke, also eine Decke auf der z.B. Hunde oder Katzen schlafen, oder eine Decke, die man über z.B. über Möbelstücke legt, um sie beim Ausmalen vor Farbspritzern zu schützen.

Comment: @Qohelet Perhaps you woukd like to comment my answer to https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/61469/what-are-some-words-only-used-in-hessen/61481#61481 ?

Answer (score 0):

Google sagt: eine „Goltar“ ist eine abgesteppte Bettdecke. Quelle: Vorarlberger Mundart- Wörterbuch, Hubert Allgäuer.